# FIELDS_CHANGE mutation with connection field

Tags: relayjs

I'm trying to understand how Relay works.

1.) Let's say I have **UpdateProductMutation** (FIELDS_CHANGE type) that updates fields of single product i.e. 'title', 'description', etc. I can send mutation with those fields changes and it works. (Say the product here is `Banana`)

2.) Now I add **product_categories** field of type *ProductCategoryConnection* to the Product type. And in the **UpdateProductMutation** mutation, I send "catIds" array as additional inputField of the mutation. (i.e. `catIds: {type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLID)}`) It also successfully mutates the Product with the *product_categories* field.

3.) To make it easier to follow, let's say `Banana` product had `Fruit` and `Yellow` categories. And I've added `Healthy` in step 2.)

4.) Problem is, if I've queried `Healthy` page before step 2. and Relay already has the cache in store, visiting `Healthy` page again after step 2. doesn't show newly associated product, `Banana`.

This is my mutation config and fat query.

```
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on UpdateProductPayload {
      updatedProduct,
    }
  `;
}

getConfigs() {
  console.warn('getConfigs', this.props);
  return [{
    type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
    fieldIDs: {updatedProduct: this.props.id},
  }];
}
```

I'm not sure if I understand it totally wrong. It seems like FIELDS_CHANGE is not the correct type to use here because the mutation works fine and the mutation payload gives the changed product category edge. The problem occurs only when I go to the previously fetched related product category page and don't see the updated product there. (Relay doesn't even send the query again). From my understanding, RANGE_ADD or RANGE_DELETE don't allow you to change the normal field either (i.e. 'title', 'description', etc.) Also in my case, catIds array could either cause RANGE_ADD or RANGE_DELETE, depends on the selection on the page.

Any advise on which direction I should take?